# Buddhist chant from video game

Tags: modern-world, chant, media, mantra

In the old game, Afterlife (Lucas Arts), there is a song that features a chant. The song is the most peaceful of the soundtrack, in my opinion, and I have always wondered what the chant was. The song can be found here: http://youtu.be/g3bXez65Fx0.

It seems that the song is Buddhist or Hindi inspired. It is similar to the chant played when founding buddhism in Civilization IV. A video of that chant can be found here: http://youtu.be/rUGH7x-i6ww.

If anyone can help me figure out what the mantra/chant of the song is, I would be eternally grateful. I cannot find an answer via Google.

Comment: the first one sounds like "OM MANI MA OM"

Answer (score 5):

I puzzled out a similar problem on the Thai Angulimali soundtrack which did turn out to be Pali.

As you say, there seems to be two chants; one at the beginning, and another at 1:44. The on at the beginning sounds familiar; I bet it's Tibetan, maybe even [Om Mani Padme Hum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om_mani_padme_hum). I'm pretty sure you'd hear it on one of the movies about Tibetan Buddhism like Kundhun, Little Buddha, etc.

The second one sounds vaguely Indic, but nothing rings a bell. The best I can sound it out to be is something like:

*asabha savana namehe*

MobyGames ([linked](http://www.mobygames.com/game/afterlife) from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afterlife_(video_game))) says a man named [Peter McConnell](http://www.petermc.com/) did the music for Afterlife. His email is info@petermc.com. Probably the best lead.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I assume this is the chant in the middle of the song that starts around 1:44 in the first video. Do you recognize the one at the beginning of the video, or is that the one that you listed above?

Comment: Also, thank you for the email address, I just sent an email to Peter McConnell. I can update my question when I hear a response.

Comment: @HBennet right, sorry. I was referring to the second one. Updated my answer to include some speculation on the first.

Comment: @HBennet if you get an answer, post it as an answer.

Comment: I sent Peter McConnell an email in mid August, but have not yet heard from him.